# dict doesn't work in visual studio (python)

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, search, visual-studio-2017

I am taking the cs50 ai python course . I was trying to run code that involved big .csv files so the cs50 ide would show the message "killed" and not run .it would run normally with the small csv files. so I copied what i had so far into visual studio.VS would load the big csv files with no problem but it gives me the error " 'set' object is not subscriptable  "

right here

`a_id = names[source.lower()]["id"]`

this is how names was defined

```
# Maps names to a set of corresponding person_ids
names = {}

# Maps person_ids to a dictionary of: name, birth, movies (a set of movie_ids)
people = {}

# Maps movie_ids to a dictionary of: title, year, stars (a set of person_ids)
movies = {}


def load_data(directory):
    """
    Load data from CSV files into memory.
    """
    # Load people
    with open(f"{directory}/people.csv", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            people[row["id"]] = {
                "name": row["name"],
                "birth": row["birth"],
                "movies": set()
            }
            if row["name"].lower() not in names:
                names[row["name"].lower()] = {row["id"]}
            else:
                names[row["name"].lower()].add(row["id"])
```

source: is a string variable from the user.

if I hover over name it says (name:dict)

same problem here

```
 films =  people[a_id]["movies"]
```

Comment: In the line `names[row["name"].lower()] = {row["id"]}` , try removing the curly braces around {row["id"]}

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with VS - it will gives error in any IDE/editor

Comment: you say that you get error in `a_id = names[source.lower()]["id"]` but I don't see this line in your code. Your information is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```py
a_id = names[source.lower()]
```

This will set `a_id` to set of `id`s.

In your code, `names` is a map between name and id (which is set type). So you were basically trying things like `{'actor': {1, 5, 3}}['actor']['id']`.

Comment: I am not trying to make it a set. I am trying to get a value out of the dict "names".

Comment: @tifanaser using `{row["id"]}` you create `set(row["id"])` (not `dict("id: row["id"])`) in `names[row["name"].lower()]` - and `set()` doesn't uses keys so you can't use `"id"` to search elements in `set()`. Simply use `print()` to see what you have in variables in different moments.